# How to change content of div in a HTML after some time has passed and then start it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I am currently creating an app which will be a kind of Digital Display on Android. My problem is I need to show an html page with more than one regions inside it. ( or boxes that are) I am at the moment already implement that but each of those regions have more than one item to put into them. Those switches between elements of each box is done after some specific amount time. And what I am currently doing is after that time elapsed, I just load new data into the region that is elasped and then view that newly created html file with webView. However that method make unnecessary loading and take some time with android devices.

What I want to learn is, is it possible to achieve that switching between each items inside different div 's with some kind of js function?. I read some information about changing contents of divs however i cant find a way to make that after some time.

For example I have 3 different regions which are A , B and C. On A region I have 2 items which will be shown 10sec and 30 sec. On region B there is only one item to show. And also on region C lets say there are 3 different items which got 15sec-25sec-10sec durations. Also I have to show those items again and again. Is there a way to make that loop and content changing after each duration on html? Any information or code piece will be helpful since I dont know much about JS or JQuery.

About those elements inside those different regions: they are consist of text(with some animation too), rss feeds, images, videos, embedded htmls.

```
textRender += String.format("<div id='text' style='position:relative; overflow:hidden; width: %dpx; height: %dpx; 
                              left: %dpx; top: %dpx'>", widthOfRegio - 10, heightOfRegio,leftOfRegio,topOfRegio);
textRender += String.format("<div id='innerText' style='position:absolute; %s:" + /*leftOfRegio+*/"0px; top: "+/*topOfRegio+*/"0px; 
width: %dpx; %s'>%s</div></div>", startPosition, widthOfRegio-10, textWrap, toTest);
```

with this code segment for example i write each element to html file. And also i generate different id's for each of new element i created. For example if i have 3 regions like the example above, i have 3 different boxes with different ids. And i use those tags with some js function which help me to make texts float left right and etc.

And here is the raw generated html looks like:

```
<div id='text' style='position:relative; overflow:hidden; width: 310px; height: 300px; left: 0px; top: 20px'>
<div id='innerText' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 310px; '><iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i31ww8ou/n514/fn6/fs8/fc9ff/tc000/ftb/bas0/bat1/bacfff/tt0/tw1/th1/ta1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="70" height="24"></iframe></div></div> 
<div id='text1' style='position:relative; overflow:hidden; width: 96px; height: 100px; left: 160px; top: -300px'>
<div id='innerText1' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 96px; '><p><em><strong><span style="color:#8b4fff;">Some Text Goes Here</span></strong></em></p></div></div> 
<div id='text2' style='position:relative; overflow:hidden; width: 96px; height: 100px; left: 53px; top: -306px'>
<div id='innerText2' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 96px; '><p><em><strong><span style="color:#8b4fff;">Some Text Goes Here</span></strong></em></p></div></div>
```

I am using that kind of structure to make texts and rss feeds work with my function. It takes those 2 ids to work with so thats why I create 2 different div id for one region atm.

Comment: can you post some simple HTML code for the example ?

Comment: I edited the post with some piece of code that lemme put it to my template html file.After writing all of those items into that template html i just fire webview to show that html.

Comment: I meant, the raw output HTML, not the way you're generating it, it does not help a lot :/

Comment: ah sorry about that i got it wrongly. ill edit my question according to it again:

Comment: I've posted a working solution, what do you think ?

Comment: its also really nice demonstration of my case pomeh thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contentAll is an object containing arrays of htmls you want to appear in different regions as time passes. 3000 and 2000 are numbers of miliseconds the functions are fired ('regionA' and 'regionB' in this case)
Take a look at jsfiddle also (link at the bottom)

```
$('#regionA').attr('data-content', 0);
$('#regionB').attr('data-content', 0);
var contentAll = {regionA: ['first content', 'second content', 'third content'],
                  regionB: ['etc 1', 'the same 2', 'another 3']};

changeRegion = function(id) {
    var $el = $('#'+id),
    num = $el.attr('data-content'),
    content = contentAll[id],
    numMax = content.length;

    num = (num+1)%content.length;
    $el.html(content[num]);
    $el.attr('data-content', num);
};

setInterval(function(){
        changeRegion('regionA');
    }, 3000);
setInterval(function(){
        changeRegion('regionB');
    }, 2000);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pVzjU/

in case you want each content to have different appearance time:

```
$('#regionA').attr('data-content', 0);
$('#regionB').attr('data-content', 0);
var contentAll = {regionA: [['first content', 1000], ['second content', 2000], ['third content', 3000]], regionB: [['etc 1', 1000], ['another 2', 2000], ['third', 3000]]};

var changeRegion = function(id){
    var $el = $('#'+id),
    num = $el.attr('data-content'),
    content = contentAll[id],
    numMax = content.length,
    time = null;

    num = (num+1)%content.length;
    time = content[num][1];
    $el.html(content[num][0]);
    $el.attr('data-content', num);
    console.log(content[num][0], time);
    setTimeout(function(){changeRegion(id)}, time);
};
setTimeout(function(){changeRegion('regionA')},contentAll['regionA'][0][0]);
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/pVzjU/4

Comment: thanks a lot miszy that is what i was looking for. However i got a question about setInterval function. Is it possible to pass it different time durations for each html elements since i need to do changing according to that.

Comment: that is just working perfect. thanks alot for your help and time Miszy. You really make this app work far more better with that=) but seems like 2nd region wont change with time goes. little error i guess. it s ok now thank you so much.

Comment: also Miszy can I ask one more question about this issue? what i am already implemented is a js function that is called in $(document).ready(function(). I need that function to animate some text moving on html file. So about the code that you gave in here. Where should i place it in order to still provide that animation behaviour? Just putting it after my animate function or where to put it? Coz before changing that content i may need to apply some animation or thngs to it.

Comment: there is an issue about code btw Miszy. When I tried with different number of html elements like regionA with 2 and regionB with 4 code stops working?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative version, working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/HAjrY/

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidden" data-display-time="2">
        First A content<br />
        2 seconds
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" data-display-time="4">
        Second A content<br />
        4 seconds
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        Unique B content
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="hidden" data-display-time="3">
        First C content<br />
        3 seconds
    </div>
    <div class="page hidden" data-display-time="6">
        Second C content<br />
        6 seconds
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" data-display-time="3">
        Third C content<br />
        3 seconds
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS code

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

​
Javascript code

```
// get all containers
var $containers = $( ".container:has([data-display-time])" );


function displayNext( $container, $pages, hitCount ) {
    // get the index of the next displayed page
    var nextPageIndex = hitCount % $pages.length,
        $pageToDisplay = $pages.eq( nextPageIndex ),
        // convert time to milliseconds
        displayTime = 1000*$pageToDisplay.data( "displayTime" );

    // hide all page, and show the right one
    $pages.addClass( "hidden" );
    $pageToDisplay.removeClass( "hidden" );

    // init a timer to display the next page, increment hitCount
    setTimeout(function() {
        displayNext( $container, $pages, hitCount+1 );
    }, displayTime );
}

// initialize the process once for each container
$containers.each(function() {
    var $container = $(this),
        $pages = $container.find( "[data-display-time]" ),
        hitCount = 0;

    // nothing to show
    if( $pages.length === 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    // nothing to rotate with, display the unique page
    else if( $pages.length === 1 ) {
        $pages.removeClass( "hidden" );
        return;
    }

    // init the rotation process
    displayNext( $container, $pages, hitCount );
});
```

​

Comment: thanks for your answer pomeh. thats another useful method which is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() function:

```
var bar = function ()
{
   $('#foo').html(Math.random())
   setTimeout(bar, 2000)
}
setTimeout(bar, 2000)
```

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/47uRA/

Comment: ok but how can i apply that function to for example 3 different regions on html? Also about duration of each item inside those regions, how can i handle it? anyway thnx for your comment

Comment: It's better to use setInterval in this case.

Comment: @Miszy not it's not. See here for more info http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful